# Count checkboxes click in grandchild component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Main app:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      totalCheckBoxes: 0,
      checkboxesClicked: 0,
      percentage: 0,
    };

    this.checkboxClick = this.checkboxClick.bind(this);
  }

  checkboxClick(type) {
    (type) ? this.setState({ checkboxesClicked: checkboxesClicked++ }) :
      (type > 0) ? this.setState({ checkboxesClicked: checkboxesClicked-- }) : this.setState({ checkboxesClicked: 0 });
  }

  render() {
    // grab steps
    const { steps } = this.props;
    const { totalCheckBoxes } = this.state;
    const { checkboxClick } = this;

    // add rendered steps to .allTheSteps
    return (
      ce('div', { className:'allTheSteps' },
        ce(pagination, { steps }),
        Object.values(steps).map((step, i) =>
          ce(Steps, { step, key: v4(), i, checkboxClick }),
        )
      )
    );
  };

};
```

Child component:

```
const Steps = ({ step, i, checkboxClick }) =>
  ce( "div", {
      className: `mainBoxes clearfix playbook_step_${i}`,
      key: v4(),
    },
      ce('span', {
        className: 'steps'
      }, step.id + 1 + ' - '),
      ce("strong", {
        className: "titleText",
        key: v4(),
      }, step.name),
      ( step.summary.length ) ? ce('div', { className: 'step__summary' }, step.summary) : null,
      ce( "div", {
        className: "stepArticle__content",
        key: v4(),
      },
        step.articles.map(({ name, url }, j) => ce(Articles, { name, url, key: v4(), j, checkboxClick }))
      )
    );
```

Grandchild component:

```
class Articles extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notes: false,
      questions: false,
    };
    this.addNotes = this.addNotes.bind(this);
    this.askQuestions = this.askQuestions.bind(this);
  }

  addNotes() {
    this.setState({ notes: !this.state.notes });
  }

  askQuestions() {
    this.setState({ questions: !this.state.questions });
  }

  render(){
    const { name, url, checkboxClick } = this.props;
    const { notes, questions } = this.state;
    const { addNotes, askQuestions } = this;

    return ce('div', null, Article( { name, url, notes, questions, addNotes, askQuestions, checkboxClick } ));

  }

}

const Article = ({ name, url, notes, questions, addNotes, askQuestions, checkboxClick }) => (
  ce('div', { className: 'stepArticle step__'},
    ce('div', {className: 'clearfix'},
        ce('div', {className: 'articleTitle'},
          ce('input', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            name: 'done',
            onClick: checkboxClick.bind(null, this),
            className: 'checkBoxes'}
            ),
          ce('a', {
            className: 'checkLink',
            target: '_blank',
            href: url
          }, name),
        ),
        ce('div', {className: 'articleActions'},
          ce('input', {
            type: 'button',
            value: 'Make Notes',
            className: 'addNotes',
            onClick: addNotes,
          }),
          ce('input', {
            type: 'button',
            value: 'Ask Clausehound',
            className: 'askQuestions',
            onClick: askQuestions,
          }),
        )
      ),
    (notes) ? ce('textarea', {
      className: 'text_areas notes notes__',
      placeholder: 'My Notes: '
    }) : null,
    (questions) ? ce('textarea', {
      className: 'text_areas questions questions__',
      placeholder: 'Questions for Clausehound Research Team: ',
    }) : null,
  )
);
```

The app is a step by step instruction/tutorial and when a user is done with a step, they tick the checkbox and a percentage for completion is displayed. I want to calculate the percentage of checkboxes that have been clicked.

Currently I am trying to do this in `checkboxClick` function in the parent component. Is this the correct approach? The `type` needs to be a boolean so that we know whether a checkbox was checked or unchecked.

[Codesandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvqNVgv0)

Comment: Would be much helpful if you would drop your code into codesandbox. It's pretty easy :)

Comment: How readable jsx...

Comment: How helpful comment...

Comment: @Kinduser: I have created the sandbox but I  am having difficulties removing errors there. Link is added if you want to check it out.

Comment: Why did you add so many files, even tests? We just need a minimal and working example :)

Comment: @Kinduser: I am fairly new with reactjs, my apologies.

Comment: It looks like Angular project :)

Comment: React only project.

Comment: Done, it is working now. @Kinduser

Comment: And what exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: There is a progressbar that should display the percentage based on checkboxes. Simply put, percentage = checkboxesClicked * 100 / totalCheckBoxes.